# Updating a Subdocument in MongoDB Using PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

I am trying to update a MongoDB document via PHP and am having difficulty figuring out why the update isn't taking.

Example Mongo document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("65cae601528e6e4b03a5611f"),
    "info": "Other Info",
    "people" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("65cae601528e6e4b03a9201f"),
            "name" : "Person 1"
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("65cae601528e6e4b03a9201f"),
            "name" : "Person 2"
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to be able to update all of the fields in the second subdocument of the "people" array.

I tried breaking that into a PHP array structured object and it isn't updating correctly. For example:

```
$action = array('$set' => array("people.$.name" => $name));
$condition = array("_id" => $_id, "people" => array("$elemMatch" => array("_id" => $person_id));
```

I have tried several variations and am not sure I am even on the right path here. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Make sure you are supplying ObjectId type instead of string for the `_id` in `people`. One of the common mistakes is type mismatch.

Comment: @ray I had some other environment issues, but this was indeed one of them. Got it working. Thank you for the help. Cheers!